# Expressing ~no option but

Tags: grammar

`しかない/ほかない/よりない` - are these forms inter-changeable

`ゆうがたまでやる(しかない/ほかない/よりない)`- are all the forms correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all of the forms are correct and interchangeable for meaning.

Other possible forms include よりほかない and ほか（or より）しかたがない.

Colloquially and informally, you can also use っきゃない though it is heard mostly in Kanto -- やるっきゃない、いくっきゃない, etc.