# use of よりなく in this sentence

Tags: grammar

亮二が言いにくそうに、しかしそうするよりなく、彼女に話を切り出した。

It seems difficult for ryouji to say, however ____, he initiates the conversation.

Having a hard time looking よりなく up.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attributive-form + より + ない` means "have no choice but to ～". Variations include ～するほかない, ～するよりほかない.

- [Learn JLPT N2 Grammar: よりほかない (yori hoka nai)](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BB%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-yori-hoka-nai/)
- [JGram - ほかない [ほかない] (hokanai)](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=hokanai)
- [Japanese grammar よりない](http://learnjapanesedaily.com/japanese-grammar-%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-yorinai.html)
- [Expressing ~no option but](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19704/5010)